# Node.js streams audio only when alsa's arecord stops recording

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, audio, socket.io

I've been trying to create a Node.js audio streaming script using Socket.io and Node.js microphone library.

The problem is that Socket.io does not pipe the audio to a remote server when SoX/ALSA is still recording the audio.

audio-stream-tx (client):

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var mic = require('microphone');
var fs = require('fs');

var socket = io.connect('ws://localhost:25566');
var stream = ss.createStream();

ss(socket).emit('stream-data', stream);

mic.startCapture();

mic.audioStream.pipe(stream);

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    mic.stopCapture();
    console.log('Got SIGINT. Press Control-D to exit.');
});
```

audio-stream-rx (server):

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = 25566;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ss(socket).on('stream-data', function(stream, data) {
        console.log('Incoming> Receiving data stream.');
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(Date.now() + ".wav", { flags: 'a' }));
    });
});

io.listen(port);
```

The [microphone library](https://github.com/vincentsaluzzo/node-microphone/blob/master/index.js) spawns either a SoX/ALSA command (depending on the platform) to record the microphone's audio. The scripts above work fine though. Just that the audio data is only piped to the stream once `mic.stopCapture()` is called.

Is there a workaround to force socket.io-stream to stream audio data the moment `mic.startCapture()` is called?

Comment: as I see the data is passed this way: `ps.pipe(encoder).pipe(audio)` so it depends on how the data is processed by the `encoder` stream and/or by the `ps` stream. I would try to interrupt the capturing and restart it to obtain chunks of data.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution? I'm looking to do something very similar.

Comment: @FajitaNachos unfortunately, no... we moved on to an entirely new solution instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Care to share your solution (broadly speaking)? I've looked at udp but there didn't appear to be a way to send secure messages in node.

Comment: @FajitaNachos sure! Actually we just recorded the full length of a wav file and uploaded it to a server via Azure File Services. Quite different from what we had originally intended to do.

Comment: Thanks @JiaJian. Unfortunately I can't do the same. Appreciate the comments though.